# Number of outcomes with an even number of tails when $8$ coins are tossed

Tags: probability

Suppose you toss $8$ coins. There are $2^8=256$ possible outcomes.

ex: HHHHHHHT, THHHHHHH, etc...

In how many of these outcomes are there an even number of tails?

My logic looks like this: 
$$\binom{8}{2} = \dfrac{8!}{2!6!}$$
$$\binom{8}{4} = \dfrac{8!}{4!4!}$$
$$\binom{8}{6} = \dfrac{8!}{6!2!}$$

where the sum of these answers would be the number of even tails?

Is my logic correct? Also, if it is, wouldn't tails be the same number?

Comment: Don't forget about $\frac{8}{0!8!}$ and $\frac{8}{8!0!}$ for 8 or 0 tails respectively.

Comment: When you write $8! \div 4! \times 4!$, it means $(8! \div 4!) \times 4!$.  What I suspect you mean is $$\binom{8}{4} = \frac{8!}{4!4!} = 8! \div (4! \times 4!)$$  You can type $\binom{n}{k}$ by typing \binom{n}{k} when you are in math mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you toss $n$ coins, there are $2^n$ possible outcomes. Half of those outcomes will have an even number of tails, and half will have an odd number of tails. So there are $2^{n-1}$ outcomes with even number of tails. In terms of probability $P(\text{even})=P(\text{odd})=0.5$

For $8$ coins, $2^7=128$ outcomes will have even number of tails.

Answer (score 3):

You're missing two cases - no tails and all tails. The number of outcomes where you have an even number of tails is then given by
$${8 \choose 0} + {8 \choose 2} + {8 \choose 4} + {8 \choose 6} + {8  \choose8}$$

Also a side-note : be careful about your notation. Write for instance $8! \div (2! \times 6!)$ if you want to use that notation such that the order of operations is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is correct when n things are taken with r ,k same things then total ways are $\frac{n!}{r!\cdot k!}$ but i suppose you should also include case where $0$ heads appear which is $1$ way so add $1$ to it also ways where all are tails